# nginx map directive: why is it allowed only on http level?

Tags: http, nginx, server

There is a very useful directive in Nginx `map`.

But it is possible to use it only on the `http` level (see docs here http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map).

For example, I have a `server` defined and I would like to use some conditional redirects in this server using `$url` variable. It would be very handy to use this directive inside `server` but it is not possible. **Why?**

Yes, I can do it also on the `http` level but there may be different `server`s defined on the `http` level and I would like to keep these conditions inside `server` section they are defined for.

Answer (score 27):

Pretty old post but I really want to bring some light into the darkness. The answer itself is quite simple.

DR;TL **Variables in NGINX are always global and once defined accessable from anywhere in the configuration. Therefore it would not make any sense to define a  map in a `server` or `location` block.**

`map` creates a new variable whose value depends on values of one or more of the source variables specified in the first parameter.

example configuration:

```
map $host $myvar {
example.com "test";
foo.com     "for";

}
```

As variables in NGINX are ALWAYS global and once defined available anywhere else in the configuration. So it wouldn't make any sense to move the map into a location or server block. The interesting fact with our `map` directive is when the variable `myvar` will receive its value or when it will be assigned?

**map assigns the value to the variable once the variable will be used in your configuration**

That means you can define the map in the http context but the value will be assigned at the point you are accessing `$myvar` in your nginx configuration.

Back to your question:
As NGINX variables are always global, having a `map` per `server` block would not make sense as they would be global anyway.

Comment: `As NGINX variables are always global having a map per server block would make sense as they would be global anyway.` Would or would not?

Comment: Would NOT. Thanks for pointing me to that one. Updated.

Answer (score 3):

I think its really about what the developer has *built* the module to be vs *how it can actually be*.

I took at look under the hood at the source code and I would suggest the same for more clarity. Also I used the following guide to understand what that code means : https://www.evanmiller.org/nginx-modules-guide.html

The source code for the  `ngx_http_map_module` is [here](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/src/http/modules/ngx_http_map_module.c).

If I look at the `static ngx_command_t  ngx_http_map_commands[] = {...}` which defines the **directives** of the module and specifically at the following snippet:

```
 { ngx_string("map"),
  NGX_HTTP_MAIN_CONF|NGX_CONF_BLOCK|NGX_CONF_TAKE2,
  ngx_http_map_block,
  NGX_HTTP_MAIN_CONF_OFFSET,
  0,
  NULL },
```

1. The first parameter just defines the directive string
2. The second parameter is interesting. Its the `type` field which is:

> type is a set of flags that indicate where the directive is legal and how many arguments the directive takes.

We see here that the fields defined are `NGX_HTTP_MAIN_CONF` which makes the directive valid at the http level. But we do not see the corresponding flags `NGX_HTTP_SRV_CONF` - for `server` or `NGX_HTTP_LOC_CONF` for `location` levels.

So it makes sense that this particular implementation of the `ngx_http_map_module` only works at the **http** level.

Now, can it work on the server/location level? Theoretically, it should. But it would need some contribution in the source code. If you think it would make for a useful feature, please do contribute :)

Answer (score -3):

The scope where `map` can be used is fixed in nginx source code. Below is part of code from ngx_http_map_module.c. You can see `map` can only be used in `NGX_HTTP_MAIN_CONF` which means `http` level only.

```
static ngx_command_t  ngx_http_map_commands[] = {                                                                                                      

    { ngx_string("map"),                                                                                                                               
      NGX_HTTP_MAIN_CONF|NGX_CONF_BLOCK|NGX_CONF_TAKE2,                                                                                                
      ngx_http_map_block,                                                                                                                              
      NGX_HTTP_MAIN_CONF_OFFSET,                                                                                                                       
      0,                                                                                                                                               
      NULL },
```

Comment: Thank you ) Do you know why it is like it is now?

Comment: Saying the software doesn't allow it is stating the obvious. Asking "why" is asking what the reasoning for that choice was.